# Автоматическая высота блоков в ряду

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть сетка с блоками, первая проблема с которой я столкнулся - блоки съезжают от переполнения, решил (временно) с помощью задания высоты блока. Отсюда вопрос. Возможно ли задавать высоту блоков **в ряду** отталкиваясь от большей высоты блока в этом же ряду?
Если возможно, то реализовать без js.

*Подразумевается что в ряду может быть разное количество элементов*

Весь код описывается [**тут**](https://itnan.ru/post.php?c=1&p=319280)

[image: Пример]

Comment: На `float` решений нет. Переходите на `grid`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.grid__col {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1rem;
  max-width: 25%;
  width: 25%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__col">
    11
  </div>
  <div class="grid__col">
    11
  </div>
  <div class="grid__col">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem, optio? Veritatis ad at doloribus quis sit optio ex debitis totam laboriosam natus. Obcaecati ad expedita rem, possimus veritatis recusandae dolorem!
  </div>
  <div class="grid__col">
    11
  </div>
  <div class="grid__col">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur!
  </div>
  <div class="grid__col">
    11
  </div>
</div>
```